# Google translate - getting non english chars

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

I'm using google translate to translate lots of words which I then store in DB, using this code:

[http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8391765/translate-text-in-c-using-google-
translate/](http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8391765/translate-text-in-c-using-google-translate/)

`string txt = Translator.TranslateText("Cosmetics", "en|sr");
 Response.Write(txt);`

Translated text (string txt) shows correctly in browser: Козметика

but source for result looks like this: `&#1050;&#1086;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1090;&#1080;&#1082;&#1072;`

Problem is I dont want to put that resulting scrambled string txt in DB, but instead want to place 'Козметика' same as I would be doing that from TextBox input.
So what is basically going on here ?

I suppose it has to do something with codepages and unicode encoding.

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are getting is the HTML encoded entities of the characters in the text. Each character is being encoded into an [HTML entity](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) to get it to display properly in browsers.

To reverse it back into the original character, you can use the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) method:

```
string encoded = "&#1050;&#1086;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1090;&#1080;&#1082;&#1072;";
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
```

This will decode the encoded text back into `Козметика`.